# Are there any ferries or public naval transportation from Victoria to Tofino?

Tags: ferries, tofino, victoria-bc

I ask because  most direct is the naval route (via the Strait of Juan de Fuca) that connects Victoria (or Port Renfrew, which can be easily accessed  vehicularly via Route 14) to Ucluelet or Tofino.

My aunt fears small airplanes and airlines, and so refuses to [fly into Tofino](http://www.tourismtofino.com/getting-to-tofino/air).

[image]

Comment: BC Ferries tend to only handle the east coast - Victoria, Nanaimo, etc.  Private vessels may exist though?

Comment: The most direct is Orca Airways. You can't beat 50 minutes by plane.

Comment: @chx Thanks, but sadly my aunt's fear precludes flying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [ferry from Port Alberni to Ucluelet](http://www.ladyrosemarine.com/), which only runs all the way to Ucluelet during the summer season.

There is no ferry from Victoria to Ucluelet or Tofino. A ferry all that way would take much more time than driving.